# Why we can't have the two issues about variance arisen in book Scala with Cats achieved both. Give me an example for each issue

Tags: scala, covariance, variant, scala-cats, contravariant

*Scala with Cats* arise two issues as follow:
[image]
And give the answer:
[image]

But it seems that it could, like:

```scala
sealed trait A
final case object B extends A
final case object C extends A

trait Printer[-T]:
  def print(t: T): Unit

implicit val aPrinter: Printer[A] = (t: A) => println(s"a printer print $t")

implicit val bPrinter: Printer[B.type] = (t: B.type) => println(s"b printer print $t")

// implicit val cPrinter: Printer[C.type] = (t: C.type) => println(s"c printer print $t")

object PrinterUse:
  def print[T](t: T)(using printer: Printer[T]): Unit =
    printer.print(t)

@main
def main():Unit =
  // issue 2
  PrinterUse.print(B)
  // b printer print B

  // issue 1
  PrinterUse.print(C)
  // a printer print C
```

I think I misunderstood some content.

I try to write example as above, and it works fine.

Comment: Is the edition of _Scala with Cats_ you're reading for Scala 2 or Scala 3? This looks to me might like it might be a Scala 2 vs 3 difference.

Comment: The scala3 launched on May 2022, and the book is publised on 2020. So I think the book is for scala 2. (By the way, the example is run with scala 3 and get the result above.)

Comment: Seth's suggestion is correct. I run the example using Scala 2 and it only prints "a printer ...". You can check the same example in Scala 2 syntax on [scalastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uwvuPGfGSd2Wz861FvM8Bg) When I swith to Scala 3, compiler stats choosing more specific implicit where possible.